# Check to check if wp_mail is working properly?

Tags: wp-mail

I'm trying to use `wp_mail` (testing on local machine) but no mail is received.
The `php.ini` has `smtp_port = 25` set and the php `mail()` is working so far.

- how can I check if wp_mail is working
- what can fail

Here is the code of my mail function:

```
function mv_optin_mail($id, $data){

    $url = $id."-".mv_mail_token($id, $data['token']);

    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_charset', 'utf8' );

    $headers[] = 'From: '.sender_signature.' <'.noreply_address.'>';    

    ob_start();
    include("optin-mail.php");
    $html_mail = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    wp_mail( $data['email'], 'Some Subject', $html_mail, $headers );
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_charset', 'utf8' );
}
```

I don't get any errors. Is there a way to toggle error-loggin for wordpress?

The `noreply_address` is `noreply@root`

Comment: Now the remaining questions are: What is `mv_mail_token()` and what does it return and where does the constant `sender_signature` come from and what does it contain?

Comment: Kaiser, listen, please try to answer the questions ... wp_mail_token() returns a string and sender_signature does at well.

Comment: [debug gist](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/4063197)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wordpress relies on the PHPMailer class to send email through PHP's `mail` function.

Since PHP's `mail` function returns very little information after execution (only TRUE or FALSE), I suggest temporarily stripping down your `mv_optin_mail` function to a minimum in order to see if the `wp_mail` functions works.

Example:

```
$mailResult = false;
$mailResult = wp_mail( 'youremail@bla.com', 'test if mail works', 'hurray' );
echo $mailResult;
```

Since you've tested PHP's `mail` function already, the mail should arrive.

If it does not, the problem lies in the other statements of your function or in the  PHPMailer class.

In cases like this, I usually rename my function to something like:

```
function mv_optin_mail_backup( $id, $data ) {
```

And add a temporary function with the same name to mess around with like so:

```
function mv_optin_mail( $id, $data ) {
    $mailResult = false;
    $mailResult = wp_mail( 'youremail@bla.com', 'test if mail works', 'hurray' );
    echo $mailResult;
}
```

When I have figured out what the problem is, I start using the backup version again.

To send a mail using PHPMailer directly you can do something like this (not for production, just for debugging):

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_example' );
function my_phpmailer_example( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    //$phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
    //    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true; // Force it to use Username and Password to authenticate
    $phpmailer->Port = 25;
    //    $phpmailer->Username = 'yourusername';
    //    $phpmailer->Password = 'yourpassword';

    // Additional settings…
    //$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // Choose SSL or TLS, if necessary for your server
    $phpmailer->setFrom( "fromemail@bla.com", "From Name" );
    $phpmailer->addAddress( "youremail@bla.com", "Your name" );
    $phpmailer->Subject    = "Testing PHPMailer";           
    $phpmailer->Body     = "Hurray! \n\n Great.";
    if( !$phpmailer->send() ) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $phpmailer->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }                       

}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use the 'wp_mail_failed' action to catch a send error.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_failed/

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do to test if `wp_mail()` is sending e-mails properly is just registering on my website with another e-mail address and seeing if the e-mail arrives. If it does, it means that WordPress is properly sending e-mails (it uses `wp_mail()` to send registration e-mails) and you should inspect your mail sending function for any errors. To do that, as @Tobias suggested, you should strip everything from your mail sending function and only leave the basic:

```
function wpse_100047() {
    echo wp_mail( 'youremail@example.com', 'WP Mail Test', 'Mail is working' );
}
```

Additionally, the e-mails sent by WordPress (as all e-mails sent by PHP's `mail()` function might be blocked by some e-mail servers (or marked as spam) so it's always a good idea to use SMTP (multiple plugins that do that) for e-mails on the live website.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by enabling [WP_DEBUG](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) in wp-config and see if that shows you anything about your code or the code for the wp_mail function. That is about it for debugging right out of the box with WP.

Also, you can use [Easy WP SMTP](http://wp-ecommerce.net/?p=2197) and enable debugging and/or set that up to use SMTP. There are similar plugins on WordPress.org but I know this one has a good debug option. If something like GMail works then you'll know it is a server setting and not this code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop the script and just see the $error object, try adding this BEFORE the `wp_mail()` method fires:

```
add_action('wp_mail_failed', function ($error) {
    wp_die("<pre>".print_r($error, true)."</pre>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting suggestions were in this document.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

In particular working with Azure Virtual Machine the SELinux config was blocking the outgoing connections.

> If you see an error like
>   `SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13)`
>   , you may be running into SELinux preventing PHP
>   or the web server from sending email. This is particularly likely on
>   RedHat / Fedora / Centos. Using the `getsebool` command we can check if
>   the httpd daemon is allowed to make a connection over the network and
>   send an email:
>
> ```
> getsebool httpd_can_sendmail 
> getsebool httpd_can_network_connect
> ```
>
> This command will return a boolean on or off. If it's off, we can turn it on:
>
> ```
> sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1 
> sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
> ```
>
> If you're running PHP-FPM via fastcgi, you
>   may need to apply this to the fpm daemon rather than httpd.