# password reset link not being sent

Tags: email, password, reset

I have wordpress 6.3. when I click the "Send password reset" link in the users menu, no email is sent. All other emails are sent, including when the user resets their own password from the login page work fine. There are no errors in the log, and word press says the email is sent. I am not sure where to even start to figure out why. Any help is appreciated

Comment: It might be worth checking the wp_mail_failed filter, e.g. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/382655

Comment: Are you using regular SMTP or do you have a mail plugin? I'd try and verify that wp_mail() is being called correctly, and if possible log out the SMTP traffic to see exactly what's going on on the wire.

Comment: are you sure it's not being sent? Or is it being sent but it's not being recieved? Your email provider may be recieving and rejecting the email as part of its security and anti-spam measures, it's a common issue with shared hosting, especially if you're trying to send email in bulk or another person on the same server tries this

Comment: yeah I am using an SMTP plugin. its not going to spam or anything. The email is a gmail inbox and i checked all the spam folders. I will have to capture on the wire to see what is happening for sure

Answer (score 0):

see if your WordPress can send other emails because if it is a configuration issue that can be fixed.  Download a plugin to send mail or write your own or something to test the mail connection.